# Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 with TCP/IP Enabled in SQL Server Configuration Manager

Tags: sql-server, iis, tcp, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to understand if it is a requirement to install IIS in order to enable TCP/IP communications in SQL Server Configuration Manager with Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2.

I would prefer to have the database on its own server with TCP/IP enabled, and then IIS w/ PHP on a 2nd server, that points to the database at another IP address.  I just want to confirm that IIS is not required in the database server for this functionality to exist.

Thanks.

Comment: IIS is not necessary for SQL Server to work

Comment: @Squirrel so every feature in SQL Server is functional without IIS?

Comment: both are different products and they install what is needed during installation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIS and SQL Server both are different and can work independently. You don't require IIS to make sure that your SQL Server is working correctly i.e., they both work independently. However if you want then you can configure IIS with SQL Server. You can follow this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/674930/Configuring-IIS-ASP-NET-and-SQL-Server) to configure it.